# content_by_lua code is not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I have implemented lua-resty-http module on nginx lua. but content_by_lua code in nginx.conf file is not working(means not fired).

nginx.conf code:

```
server {
location {

 content_by_lua '
        local http = require "resty.http.simple"
      local httpc = http.new()
      httpc:set_timeout(500)
      httpc:connect("127.0.0.1", 80)
        local res, err = httpc:request({
          path = "/example/sample/test",
          headers = {
              ["Host"] = "example.abc.com",
          },
      })
 ';
}
}
```

Any solution??

Comment: Shouldn't it be `location / {` instead of `location {` ? Also in the `content_by_lua`, you didn't return anything as such

Comment: Ya it should be location /test { } , in content_by_lua if i didn't return any thing but at least request has to be success but request is not fired. For debugging purpose i have changed one nginx variable value to something using ngx.vars.a = 2 but value is also not changed.